# Opening a file from internal storage on Android Studio from a class that doesn't extend AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, android-internal-storage

Is it possible to read a file from internal storage in a utility class that doesn't extend anything? I have the code below to read a file, but I can't use the openFileInput method because it doesn't exist. Is there something I have to import to read these files?

```
private String readFromFile(String fileName) {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = openFileInput("Links"); // this doesn't compile in a utility class
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        return String.valueOf(sb);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `openFileInput` is a method of `Context` so you could pass one of those to the `readFromFile` method.

Comment: @nash yes that better, you should add as answer.